# ListView Null Pointer in Tabbed Design

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

Thanks for your time.

I am following https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-adapter and extending it into tabbed views.  The original code was:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false );

        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>( this.getActivity(), "Todo" );
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
        mainAdapter.setImageKey("image");

        // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        Log.d("First","Output"); // This will show on logcat
        listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        Log.d("Second","Output"); // This is not shown on logcat
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

It compiles but crashes on a null pointer seemingly either in **listView** or **mainAdapter** and I don't know what has changed to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

because Fragment doesn't have findViewById method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Ok done.  And I have the following code to check for whether this is working: Log.d( "Pre setAdapter", "no crash"); listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter); Log.d( "Post setAdapter", "No crash." ); I get the output still from the first log but the second never outputs...

Comment: Did you actually tested this code? Also show us your XML for fragment_list.xml

Comment: Yep.      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is because you're missing rootView. If you really tried this code show us your logcat. Edit your question and post it there.

Comment: SHOW US YOUR LOGCAT BABY lol no it works, I had my Parse.initialize line commented out like a dumbass.  Good job and thanks!